# Screenshot and paste in new email - outlook excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for codes that would screenshot display in my screen (not the whole screen). I got already a program with the help of google but unfortunately, the program is just pasting the screenshot in excel. How could I paste it directly to new email in Outlook? Thanks. Btw here's the code that I got.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const CCHDEVICENAME = 32
Private Const CCHFORMNAME = 32
Private Const SRCCOPY = &HCC0020 ' (DWORD) destination = source

Private Type DEVMODE
  dmDeviceName As String * CCHDEVICENAME
  dmSpecVersion As Integer
  dmDriverVersion As Integer
  dmSize As Integer
  dmDriverExtra As Integer
  dmFields As Long
  dmOrientation As Integer
  dmPaperSize As Integer
  dmPaperLength As Integer
  dmPaperWidth As Integer
  dmScale As Integer
  dmCopies As Integer
  dmDefaultSource As Integer
  dmPrintQuality As Integer
  dmColor As Integer
  dmDuplex As Integer
  dmYResolution As Integer
  dmTTOption As Integer
  dmCollate As Integer
  dmFormName As String * CCHFORMNAME
  dmUnusedPadding As Integer
  dmBitsPerPel As Long
  dmPelsWidth As Long
  dmPelsHeight As Long
  dmDisplayFlags As Long
  dmDisplayFrequency As Long
End Type

Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long 
Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Declare Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hDestDC As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hSrcDC As Long, ByVal xSrc As Long, ByVal ySrc As Long, ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long
Declare Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, lpInitData As DEVMODE) As Long
Declare Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long
Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long

Declare Function CountClipboardFormats Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Declare Function CreateIC Lib "GDI32" Alias "CreateICA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, lpInitData As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "GDI32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Declare Function EnumClipboardFormats Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long

Sub GetPrintScreen()
   Call CaptureScreen(35, 200, 975, 445)
End Sub
```

I think this is the part that I should edit.

```
Public Sub ScreenToGIF_NewWorkbook()
Dim wbDest As Workbook, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim FromType As String, PicHigh As Single
Dim PicWide As Single, PicWideInch As Single
Dim PicHighInch As Single, DPI As Long
Dim PixelsWide As Integer, PixelsHigh As Integer

Call TOGGLEEVENTS(False)
Call GetPrintScreen

If CountClipboardFormats = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Clipboard is currently empty.", vbExclamation, "Nothing to Paste"
    GoTo EndOfSub
End If

 'Determine the format of the current clipboard contents.  There may be multiple
 'formats available but the Paste methods below will always (?) give priority
 'to enhanced metafile (picture) if available so look for that first.
If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(14) <> 0 Then
    FromType = "pic"
ElseIf IsClipboardFormatAvailable(2) <> 0 Then
    FromType = "bmp"
Else
    MsgBox "Clipboard does not contain a picture or bitmap to paste.", _
    vbExclamation, "No Picture"
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.StatusBar = "Pasting from clipboard ..."

Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets(1)
wbDest.Activate
wsDest.Activate
wsDest.Range("B3").Activate

 'Paste a picture/bitmap from the clipboard (if possible) and select it.
 'The clipboard may contain both text and picture/bitmap format items.  If so,
 'using just ActiveSheet.Paste will paste the text.  Using Pictures.Paste will
 'paste a picture if a picture/bitmap format is available, and the Typename
 'will return "Picture" (or perhaps "OLEObject").  If *only* text is available,
 'Pictures.Paste will create a new TextBox (not a picture) on the sheet and
 'the Typename will return "TextBox".  (This condition now checked above.)
On Error Resume Next 'just in case
wsDest.Pictures.Paste.Select
On Error GoTo 0

 'If the pasted item is an "OLEObject" then must convert to a bitmap
 'to get the correct size, including the added border and matting.
 'Do this via a CopyPicture-Bitmap and then a second Pictures.Paste.
If TypeName(Selection) = "OLEObject" Then
    With Selection
        .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
        .Delete
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
         'Modify the FromType (used below in the suggested file name)
         'to signal that the original clipboard image is not being used.
        FromType = "ole object"
    End With
End If

 'Make sure that what was pasted and selected is as expected.
 'Note this is the Excel TypeName, not the clipboard format.
If TypeName(Selection) = "Picture" Then
    With Selection
        PicWide = .Width
        PicHigh = .Height
        .Delete
    End With
Else
     'Can get to here if a chart is selected and "Copy"ed instead of "Copy Picture"ed.
     'Otherwise, ???.
    If TypeName(Selection) = "ChartObject" Then
        MsgBox "Use Shift > Edit > Copy Picture on charts, not just Copy.", _
        vbExclamation, "Got a Chart Copy, not a Chart Picture"
    Else
        MsgBox "Excel pasted a '" & TypeName(Selection) & "' instead of a Picture.", _
        vbExclamation, "Not a Picture"
    End If
     'Clean up and quit.
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    GoTo EndOfSub
End If

 'Add an empty embedded chart, sized as above, and activate it.
 'Positioned at cell B3 just for convenient debugging and final viewing.
 'Tip from Jon Peltier:  Just add the embedded chart directly, don't use the
 'macro recorder method of adding a new separate chart sheet and then relocating
 'the chart back to a worksheet.
With Sheets(1)
    .ChartObjects.Add(.Range("B3").Left, .Range("B3").Top, PicWide, PicHigh).Activate
End With

 'Paste the [resized] bitmap into the ChartArea, which creates ActiveChart.Shapes(1).
On Error Resume Next
ActiveChart.Pictures.Paste.Select
On Error GoTo 0
If TypeName(Selection) = "Picture" Then
    With ActiveChart
         'Adjust the position of the pasted picture, aka ActiveChart.Shapes(1).
         'Adjustment is slightly greater than the .ChartArea.Left/Top offset, why ???
         ''''         .Shapes(1).IncrementLeft -1
         ''''         .Shapes(1).IncrementTop -4
         'Remove chart border.  This must be done *after* all positioning and sizing.
         '         .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
    End With

     'Show pixel size info above the picture-in-chart-soon-to-be-GIF/JPEG/PNG.
    PicWideInch = PicWide / 72 'points to inches ("logical", not necessarily physical)
    PicHighInch = PicHigh / 72
    DPI = PixelsPerInch() 'typically 96 or 120 dpi for displays
    PixelsWide = PicWideInch * DPI
    PixelsHigh = PicHighInch * DPI
Else
     'Something other than a Picture was pasted into the chart.
     'This is very unlikely.
    MsgBox "Clipboard corrupted, possibly by another task."
End If

EndOfSub:
   Call TOGGLEEVENTS(True)
End Sub

Public Sub TOGGLEEVENTS(blnState As Boolean)
 'Originally written by Zack Barresse
  With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = blnState
    .EnableEvents = blnState
    .ScreenUpdating = blnState
    If blnState Then .CutCopyMode = False
    If blnState Then .StatusBar = False
  End With
End Sub

Public Function PixelsPerInch() As Long

Application.DefaultWebOptions.PixelsPerInch.
Dim hdc As Long
hdc = CreateIC("DISPLAY", vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
PixelsPerInch = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, 88) 'LOGPIXELSX = 88 = Logical pixels/inch in X
DeleteDC (hdc)
End Function

Public Sub CaptureScreen(Left As Long, Top As Long, Width As Long, Height As Long)
Dim srcDC As Long, trgDC As Long, BMPHandle As Long, dm As DEVMODE
srcDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", "", "", dm)
trgDC = CreateCompatibleDC(srcDC)
BMPHandle = CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcDC, Width, Height)
SelectObject trgDC, BMPHandle
BitBlt trgDC, 0, 0, Width, Height, srcDC, Left, Top, SRCCOPY
OpenClipboard 0&
EmptyClipboard
SetClipboardData 2, BMPHandle
CloseClipboard
DeleteDC trgDC
ReleaseDC BMPHandle, srcDC
End Sub
```